# XAML ListBox to TextBox Update code

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, textbox, listbox

I know i've asked variants of this question before, but after quite a few hours of testing and researching. I've managed to get my XAML code to 50% of how I want it to work, and I need help with the rest. 
I've got my xaml code to load an XML file into a Listbox, and bound my textbox to the listbox. However, The textbox's text will not update when I select another value in the ListBox.

```
<Window x:Class="BeginnersJapanese.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="274" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlData"
                   Source="https://www.dropbox.com/s/jgw84kqj2k1bwq1/JapaneseEnglishData.xml?dl=1"
                   XPath="WordList/Word"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,1">
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Name="XmlData" Source="https://www.dropbox.com/s/jgw84kqj2k1bwq1/JapaneseEnglishData.xml?dl=1" XPath="WordList/Word"/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Speak" Name="speakBtn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="252,158,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" Click="speakButton_Click"/>
        <ListBox Name="listBx" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/WordList/Word/English}" Height="225" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="167,110,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listBx, Path=SelectedItem.InnerText}" Text="{Binding XPath=Kanji}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Essentially, What I am trying to do is select an item in the listbox and it display the Japanese equivalent from my xml file. Which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--This is a generated XML File-->
<WordList>
  <Word>
    <English>Me</English>
    <Romaji>boku</Romaji>
    <Kanji>ぼく</Kanji>
  </Word>
  <Word>
    <English>I</English>
    <Romaji>boku</Romaji>
    <Kanji>ぼく</Kanji>
  </Word>
  <Word>
    <English>Me</English>
    <Romaji>watashi</Romaji>
    <Kanji>わたし</Kanji>
  </Word>
</WordList>
```

The current issue is the textbox will only display boku(ぼく) and will not change to watashi(わたし) when I change the Listbox to the other Me word in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to make it work without changing much of your current code, modify the `TextBox`'s `DataContext` and `Text` properties binding as follow :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/WordList/Word/English}" .... />
<TextBox DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listBx, Path=SelectedItem}" 
         Text="{Binding XPath=../Kanji}" ..... />
```

**Some brief explanations :**

`XPath` only worked for XmlDocument/XmlElement `DataContext`, and `InnerText` is not. That's why I change the `TextBox`'s `DataContext` binding to point to the `ListBox`'s `SelectedItem` (`SelectedItem` contains an `XmlElement` representing `<English>` node).

Then I need to also change the Xpath for `TextBox`'s `Text` property. Since `SelectedItem` points to `<English>` node, you need to climb up one level to get to `<Word>` element using XPath `..`, and from there get down one level to `<Kanji>` element using XPath `/Kanji`.

Another possible XPath to get to `<Kanji>` node starting form `<English>` node is by using `following-sibling` axes :

```
Text="{Binding XPath=following-sibling::Kanji}"
```

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I was having so many issues trying to puzzle this out @har07. Not only did you explain how XPath works, you did it in a way that most sites I went to did not.

Comment: Always happier to know that someone understand what I'm talking about instead of just finding the codes worked for him like magic. Glad to hear that, you're welcome :)